# How do I add an EdgeNGramTokenFilter to a Compass Query?

Tags: lucene, compass-lucene

I am building some auto-complete functionality using compass and I need to add an *EdgeNGramTokenFilter* to the compass query but I cannot see how I can add it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to add the `EdgeNGramTokenFilter` filter by creating a provider class adding a reference to it in the `compass.config.xml`  file by adding the following line within the  `<searchEngine>` tags

```
<analyzerFilter name="lower" type="EdgeNGramTokenFilterProvider"/>
```

Here is the class:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.EdgeNGramTokenFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.EdgeNGramTokenFilter.Side;
import org.compass.core.CompassException;
import org.compass.core.config.CompassSettings;
import org.compass.core.lucene.engine.analyzer.LuceneAnalyzerTokenFilterProvider;

public class EdgeNGramTokenFilterProvider implements LuceneAnalyzerTokenFilterProvider {

    public TokenStream createTokenFilter(TokenStream tokenStream) {
        return new EdgeNGramTokenFilter(tokenStream, Side.FRONT, 1, 20);
    }

    public void configure(CompassSettings settings) throws CompassException {
    }

}
```