# Implementing Auto-Complete with Compass Search Engine

Tags: java, autocomplete, compass-lucene

I am using Compass Search Engine to facilitate searching on a web solution that I am working on at the moment. The search is working fine, but now I would like to implement an auto-complete facility using Compass.

I could not find / figure out how this could be implemented on top of Compass. I think this should be a common requirement and there should be an easy way to do it. Appreciate if someone with experience in Compass could help out.

Thanks.

Comment: I remember Compass based on Lucene, so you can use `search*` to find matches while typing. eg. `t*, ty*, typ*`.... you will get `typing` as suggestions from your database. You have a database to search, right?

Comment: Hi Eric, you are correct that Compass is based on Lucene. But I want to stick to Compass API, and I could not find a method in it that serves my purpose. I can get a CompassHits object by running a query, but it returns Objects, not terms. I want to get a list of matching keywords, not objects.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into making an EdgeNGramTokenFilter.

This might be helpful.

[Compass Query auto-complete functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200474/how-do-i-add-an-edgengramtokenfilter-to-a-compass-query)